# Excel VBA - Creating a new Excel sheet based on data values from another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have an EXCEL data set that I need to transform into a more condensed format using values in the data set itself.

The original data set looks like this:

**State,City,Sports category,Subcategory,Jan 2011,Feb 2011,Mar 2011**

```
NSW,Paramatta,Field,Cricket,3,2,1
NSW,Paramatta,Field,Soccor,2,2,2
VIC,Bundoora,Indoor,Table Tennic,1,3,2
VIC,Bundoora,Indoor,Swimming,1,2,2
```

Each row (the first four fields) must repeat itself depending on the number of instances under the date fields. The value on a new filed should be the date of the occurrence. E.g., The first entry above should become 6 entries with 3 for Jan, 2 for Feb and 1 for Mar.

The result should look like this:

**State,City,Sports category,Subcategory,Date**

```
NSW,Paramatta,Field,Cricket,Jan-11
NSW,Paramatta,Field,Cricket,Jan-11
NSW,Paramatta,Field,Cricket,Jan-11
NSW,Paramatta,Field,Cricket,Feb-11
NSW,Paramatta,Field,Cricket,Feb-11
NSW,Paramatta,Field,Cricket,Mar-11
NSW,Paramatta,Field,Soccor,Jan-11
NSW,Paramatta,Field,Soccor,Jan-11
NSW,Paramatta,Field,Soccor,Feb-11
NSW,Paramatta,Field,Soccor,Feb-11
NSW,Paramatta,Field,Soccor,Mar-11
VIC,Bundoora,Indoor,Table Tennic,Jan-11
VIC,Bundoora,Indoor,Table Tennic,Feb-11
VIC,Bundoora,Indoor,Table Tennic,Feb-11
VIC,Bundoora,Indoor,Table Tennic,Feb-11
VIC,Bundoora,Indoor,Table Tennic,Mar-11
VIC,Bundoora,Indoor,Table Tennic,Mar-11
VIC,Bundoora,Indoor,Swimming,Jan-11
VIC,Bundoora,Indoor,Swimming,Feb-11
VIC,Bundoora,Indoor,Swimming,Feb-11
VIC,Bundoora,Indoor,Swimming,Mar-11
VIC,Bundoora,Indoor,Swimming,Mar-11
```

Would someone be able to put together a VBA script for this?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm sure someone would, but that's not really the point of this place...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub mcr_Expand_Match_Data()
    Dim lc As Long, lr As Long, rw As Long, d As Long, m As Long
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet7")  'source worksheet
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet8")  'target worksheet
    With ws2
        .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.ClearContents
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, 5) = Array("State", "City", "Sports category", "Subcategory", "Date")
    End With
    With ws1
        lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lc = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For rw = 2 To lr
            For d = 5 To lc
                For m = 1 To .Cells(rw, d).Value
                    ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 4) = _
                      .Cells(rw, 1).Resize(1, 4).Value
                    ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 4) = _
                      .Cells(1, d).Value
                Next m
            Next d
        Next rw
    End With
    Set ws2 = Nothing
    Set ws1 = Nothing
End Sub
```

You will need to change the source and target worksheet names in the third and fourth lines. It should survive adding additional columns of match data at the right end of the source worksheet. That will produce results as illustrated below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to UNPIVOT, Excel can do this natively.
http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/unpivot-columns-HA104053356.aspx